# Can I upload an app to the play store that has an activity with a webview in it?

Tags: android, node.js, webview

I have an app published to the play store and I've been maintaining it and adding new updates. One of those updates is a webview that redirect to a web application that I built using NodeJS.

I have two niches of users: regular people that will download the app and use it for it's intended functionality, and my partners which offer services using the website, which is then displayed in the app when regular people use it, so they can request those services from partners.

**All I want to do is add an activity that contains a webview, which redirects to the website, so my partners can use it and not have to access the website via the browser every time (i'm just trying to make it more convenient for them to use the website).**

I once tried uploading a partners app that did exactly that: only had a webview that redirected to the website, but it got struck down and I got a notice. My fear is that my currently released app will also get a notice if I try to add the webview to it's currently existing code (remember, it's just another activity. the app currently has 7 activities and was built from scratch by me over the course of the last 2 months).

My question is: will I get a notice on my current app if I add the new activity that only contains a webview? I pretend on creating an entire new app for my partners to use, but I currently don't have the time to do that, but I want to make it move convenient for them to access the website so they can use the system I built for them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Google play policies not about programming.

Comment: is there any other place i can post this question then?

Comment: then i will manually delete it myself, but i need the answer. this is the only forum that i'm a part of

Comment: Google customer support?

Comment: tried that already but haven't gotten a response until now, so i'm resorting to other places. trying to find anyone that has been in the same shoes

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can published an app which contains just a WebView of your own website. Please note that according to Google Play Developer Program Policies, it's not allowed to publish apps that provide a WebView of a website you don't own or administer:

> Do not post an app where the primary functionality is to:
>
> Provide a webview of a website not owned or administered by you (unless you have permission from the website owner/administrator to do
>   so)

Reference: http://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html

Comment: But i added an app to the playstore which contained a webview of the same website but I got a notice and now it's suspended. It's my website it even has the same domain as the package the app used, but it was suspended due to a violation of the webviews and affiliate spam policy.

Comment: i won't be able to help your more with that. you will need to try. But if you you have more activities and not just the webview, it *should* be ok

Comment: i will try to contact their support team and see if anyone else can give me some more insight. But thanks for the help, I appreciate it!

Comment: hi @ChristianW.A.Hess, have you made contact with google support team? How is the result?
I'm having this problem and I'm confused as to how to solve it, because my client just wants the website to look like an app, thanks

Comment: @sedayux I contacted them but they didn't give me a proper response. However I added the webview and uploaded the app and it is now running normally on the play store. So the problem is only uploading an app that ONLY has the primary and only function to send all your traffic to a external address. Only webview = bad; but webview + all the other stuff = good

Comment: webview+other stuff = perfect, but for suspended account, just send documents to prove that we have permission for the websit and now my account active after send the document..fiuuuh...

Comment: @sedayux what type of document you have sent to support team let me know please